# Facing error while starting Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, nosuchmethoderror

> Got this erroe while i'm starting my android studio and last time
> when i closed the android studio i was also update my android studio

```
 Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try do simply reinstall android studio? Your config files should not be touched during the reinstallation so that you can simply import them after it.